# Match Image Tag within Group of 3 or More Tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I am trying to get image tags which occur in a bunch of minimum 3 like below

```
$str = "

<img>Some image</img>

Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 

Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 

Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
<img>Some image</img>


Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 

Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 

Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 

Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 

<img>Image i need</img>
<img>Image i need</img>
<img>Image i need</img>
<img>Image i need</img>

Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 

Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 

Text Text Text Text Text Text Text

";
```

I tried the following

```
preg_match_all("/<img/is", $str, $matches);
```

But that just returns all the image tags and i tried to match some text with multiple occurrences of images but still could get it to work...any help is appreciated guys.

Thanks for the answers guys, specially zx81 and avinash but i would also like to know the same regex for this type of image tags

```
<img src='data' />
<img src='data' />
<img src='data' />
<img src='data' />
```

Thanks again guys

Comment: You might just have to change your regex to match all 3, like `/(<img>.+?</img>\s*){3,99}/is`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Array of Tags: A bit of DEFINE work

Matching the image tags one by one in regex is a bit of a mission, but it can be done:

```
(?smx)   # free-spacing, DOTALL, multi-line

# Let's define an image tag
(?(DEFINE)(?<image><img[^>]*>[^<]*</img>))

(?:
  # If what follows is 3 images
  (?=(?&image)(?:\s*^(?&image)){2})
  # OR
  |
  # We're at a continuation point, but not the beginning of the string
  (?:(?<!\A)\G)      
  # Match and drop whitespaces
  \s*\K
)
# THEN Match an image!
(?&image)
```

In [the regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/dP1aZ8/13), you can see that the correct tags are matched one by one.

**Sample PHP Code to Print All the Matches:**

```
$regex = '~(?smx)(?(DEFINE)(?<image><img[^>]*>[^<]*</img>))
(?:
  (?=(?&image)(?:\s*^(?&image)){2})
  |
  (?:(?<!\A)\G)\s*\K
)
(?&image)~';

if (preg_match_all($regex, $yourstring, $matches)) {
   print_r($matches[0]);
}
```

**Expanded Spec**

For the same pattern when the tag starts specifically with `<img src='data' />`, use this code:

```
$regex = '~(?smx)(?(DEFINE)(?<image><img[ ]src='data'[ ]/>[^<]*</img>))
(?:
  (?=(?&image)(?:\s*^(?&image)){2})
  |
  (?:(?<!\A)\G)\s*\K
)
(?&image)~';

if (preg_match_all($regex, $yourstring, $matches)) {
   print_r($matches[0]);
}
```

Comment: FYI, commented the regex, added demo, PHP code to build an array of tags.

Comment: lol ive not seen a regex code like this, this is some preg matching :D thanks a lot :D

Comment: hey what if the image tag is like this <img src='data' />, could you modify the code for that there mate....i really appreciate the help

Comment: actually this was the regex that worked for me....a bit modified                   $regex = "~(?smx)(?(DEFINE)(?<image><img[^>]* src='[^>]*'[^<]* \/>))
(?:
  (?=(?&image)(?:\s*^(?&image)){2})
  |
  (?:(?<!\A)\G)\s*\K
)
(?&image)~";

Comment: Glad to see you're feeling comfortable with it, it's a cool regex. :) Thanks for the green checkmark!

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture some parts of your match with brackets `(` and `)`. Here is an example regex with one capturing group:

```
preg_match_all("/<img>(.+?)</img>/", $str, $matches);
```

If you look at `$matches` now you see the text between the `<img>` tag is stored in a seprare entry of the array.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you need

```
(<img>.+?<\/img>\s*){3,}
```

This will capture all img tags and only if they are at least 3 in a row. This works, tested with [regex101](http://regex101.com/#javascript). Oh, and used global flag

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want,

```
/(?:<img\b[^\n]*\n){3,}/gm
```

It matches three or more consecutive image tags.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dP1aZ8/12)

Your PHP code would be,

```
$regex =  '~(?:<img\b[^\n]*\n){3,}~';
preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches);
echo var_dump($matches);
```

Output:

```
<img>Image i need</img>
<img>Image i need</img>
<img>Image i need</img>
<img>Image i need</img>
```

If you want them in a separate group index, then try the below

```
(?<!<\/img>\n)<img\b[^\n]*\n<img\b[^\n]*\n(?!<img)|(?<!<\/img>\n)<img\b[^\n]*\n(?!<img)(*SKIP)(*F)|(<img>Image i need<\/img>)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dP1aZ8/16)

Comment: Doesn't he want to match the tags one by one?

Comment: yes, he wants the consecutive(three or more) img tags.

Comment: I thought he wanted to match them one at a time, not in a block—so he can have an array of tags.

Comment: hey this works nice with /si mods with php preg_match. I wanted to know can u make it return the matched data in different indexes of arrays like 0 ,1,2 for the 3 matched img tags...

Comment: Yes i want only those which occur in a bunch of 3+ but if it could get each of the matched data in a new index of an array it would be nice :)

Comment: hey ... awesome code bro... sorry i cant pick 2 correct answers.. this works awesome with js...i'll upvote your answer there mate...thanks

Comment: js won't support `(*SKIP)(*F)`